# Counts point to polygon

Tags: qgis

I am using QGIS 2.18.10. I am working in UTM Zone 30 WGS 84.

I have created a vector grid 1000km X 1000 km using the Vector>Research Tools> Create Grid

I have another shapefile which has point data in it.

I am trying to use: Vector>Counts point in polygons, and selecting the correct dataset.

However it is giving me an error: `"unknown see log for more details"`. But that is in the log. So I can't figure out why.

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share both shapefiles?

Comment: Add the log panel to get more detail on the issue. You're looking at the tool log. Then provide more detail

Comment: A grid 1000km X 1000 km is huge and, depending on latitude, it could occupy between  2 (equator) and more than 4 (high latitudes) UTM zones.

Comment: Do both datasets have the same CRS? Does your grid have valid geometry?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you forget to choose the "**Grid Extent**" (It should be the Canvas extent or Layer)

1 - Vector> Research Tools> Vector Grid

[image]

2 - Vector> Analysis Tools> Count points in polygons

[image]